# Javascript snippet crashes web browser

Tags: javascript

This snippet in the `<head>` tag of a normal page crashes which ever browser I use it in:

```
function insert(str, position, insert) {
    var current = str;
    var start = current.slice(0, position);
    var end = current.slice(position, current.length);
    return start + insert + end;
};

var str = "1000";
var nbd = str.length;
var mod = nbd%3;

for (var i = mod; i < str.length; i+3) {
    str = insert(str,i,",");
}

console.log(str);
console.log("mod: " + mod);
```

also if the function `insert` is a prototype of string then that would crash as well:

```
String.prototype.insert(position, insert) {
    var current = this;
    var start = current.slice(0, position);
    var end = current.slice(position, current.length);
    return start + insert + end;
}
```

Comment: The `for` is an infinite loop, and 'str' grows infinitely - the page should freeze until the process runs out of memory. Try `i += 3`.

Comment: why did i get a downvote, it may be a silly mistake, but no need for the downvote is there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding three to i in your for() loop, but that value is not saved back to i. Your third clause in the for loop should be i +=3 to add 3 back to the variable i.

Answer (score 1):

`i` in for loop does not increment. Use:

```
for (var i = mod; i < str.length; i = i+3) ...
```